# How can I write a function that works on mousemove event and call it in document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that moves the objects on my screen while I move mouse pointer across my screen. To do this, I've called the function in $(document).mousemove function. Instead I need to just call my function in $(document).ready so that my function already has the mousemove property and gets executed when called.

Here's my code..

```js
(function ($) {
                $.fn.imgParallax = function (e) {
                    var d = e.effspeed;
                    var centerpos = $('p.imagemove').width() / 2;
                    var middlepos = $('p.imagemove').height() / 2;
                    var leftpos = e.pageX - centerpos;
                    var toppos = e.pageY - middlepos;
                    var xpos = (centerpos - (leftpos / d));
                    var ypos = (middlepos - (toppos / d));
                    $(this).css('left', xpos + 'px');
                    $(this).css('top', ypos + 'px');
                };
            })(jQuery);
            $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                $(".a").imgParallax({
                    effspeed: 16,
                    pageX: e.pageX,
                    pageY: e.pageY
                });
                $(".b").imgParallax({
                    effspeed: 12,
                    pageX: e.pageX,
                    pageY: e.pageY
                });
                $(".c").imgParallax({
                    effspeed: 6,
                    pageX: e.pageX,
                    pageY: e.pageY
                });
                $(".d").imgParallax({
                    effspeed: 18,
                    pageX: e.pageX,
                    pageY: e.pageY
                });
            });
```

```css
 body {
                overflow: hidden;
                background: black;
            }
            p {
                position: relative;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .a, .b, .c, .d {
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
            }
            .b {
                margin-left: -325px;
                margin-top: -284px;
            }
            .a {
                margin-left: -444px;
                margin-top: -132px;
            }
            .c {
                width: 539px;
                height: 498px;
                margin-left: -265px;
                margin-top: -250px;
            }
            .d {
                width: 1132px;
                height: 313px;
                margin-left: -500px;
                margin-top: -60px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="imagemove">
            <span class="d q"><img src="http://web2developer.in.md-in-26.webhostbox.net/themes/ideathemes/awesome-ideas/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home_slider/background.png"></span>
            <span class="a q"><img src="http://web2developer.in.md-in-26.webhostbox.net/themes/ideathemes/awesome-ideas/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home_slider/text_back.png"></span>
            <span class="b q"><img src="http://web2developer.in.md-in-26.webhostbox.net/themes/ideathemes/awesome-ideas/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/text_front.png"></span>
            <span class="c q"><img src="http://web2developer.in.md-in-26.webhostbox.net/themes/ideathemes/awesome-ideas/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/blur.png"></span>

        </p>
```

```
(function ($) {
            $.fn.imgParallax = function (e) {
                var d = e.effspeed;
                var centerpos = $('p.imagemove').width() / 2;
                var middlepos = $('p.imagemove').height() / 2;
                var leftpos = e.pageX - centerpos;
                var toppos = e.pageY - middlepos;
                var xpos = (centerpos - (leftpos / d));
                var ypos = (middlepos - (toppos / d));
                $(this).css('left', xpos + 'px');
                $(this).css('top', ypos + 'px');
                console.log(d);
            };
        })(jQuery);
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            $(".a").imgParallax({
                effspeed: 16,
                pageX: e.pageX,
                pageY: e.pageY
            });
        });
```

The 'effspeed' is actually to determine the speed at which the object moves along the screen when mouse pointer moves. 'pageX' and 'pageY' are to get the pointer co-ordinates.

Comment: whats the problem ?

Comment: Syntax is  $(function(){

 
}); Wrong syntax seems in code.

Comment: `$(document).mousemove()`

Comment: you can also have name for the handler & call it on `ready` as well as attach it on `mousemove`

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If (ahem) one of the questions below solved your problem, it's proper to check-mark is as your accepted answer.

Comment: My problem is not yet solved. But I would like to close this thread if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your html page if you can add a div to wrap up the whole boddy section try using the the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divID").mouseover(function () {
       //Your code goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to run my function in document ready i.e. $("#divID").imgParallax(); and it should work.

Comment: So now whats the problem . I dont get you clearly @ Shekhar R

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your mouse move event on document ready like this. This will provide the parallax function the mousemove event object it needs.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).trigger("mousemove"); // Trigger a "fake" mousemove event
});
$(document).mousemove(parallax);

function parallax(e) {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Comment: OP said in `document.ready`, so it should be like `function(){ ... parallax(); ... }`

Comment: What I meant was OP is asking for function **inside `ready`**, so your ready function should be like `$(document).ready(function(){... paralax() ... })`. `ready(parallax)` will assign parallax as callback and OP will not be able to do anything other that it.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. I think I've addressed both our concerns in the edited answer.

Comment: If you call thE function directly it won't have a mousemove event as an argument. See the op code example - he will need that